# Winsock2 missing some macros and functions that are defined in the documentation

Tags: c, windows-10, winsock2

I'm programming a multithreaded server in windows using winsock2 (linking with ws2_32.lib and pthread), but am having trouble trying to set a socket to persistently triggered mode.

Thanks :)

I've tried using the ProcessSocketNotifications() function with the SOCK_NOTIFY_REGISTRATION structure and the  SOCK_NOTIFY_TRIGGER_PERSISTENT flag set as the triggerFlags attribute, however none of these are defined in my version of winsock2? The macros and structures aren't in the winsock2.h file (I did a control-F), however the linker seems to not throw an error, which is weird.

I have the latest update of windows, (in the docs it says there's a minimum Windows build that was released in 2021, and my laptop updated this morning, so I'm assuming that's ok? Unless I have to somehow download a slightly different version of windows or enable a subset of features somehow, like Windows Server or something).

I'm a rookie, never programmed a windows server in c before this project.

Any help about enabling these functions, macros and structs or about a different way to set a socket to persistently triggered mode would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your actual code.  IIRC there are order dependencies in Microsoft's header files...

Comment: Since when does Windows support pthreads??

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, in the VS installer (which can be run using Tools -> "Get Tools and Features..."), that you have actually installed the latest windows SDKS. These are found on the individual components tab of the installer program. Then in your project properties (Project -> Properties) on the General page make sure that "Windows SDK Version" is either "10.0 (latest installed version)" or at least a version late enough to have the desired function/.

This has nothing to do with the version of windows you have installed, since the symbols aren't in winsock2.h you haven't even gotten to the point where the ws2_32.lib file will be examined, let alone the DLL files at run-time. It would even be possible to build a program targetting an up-to-date version of windows on a system that is very out-of-date, for the most part the build tools look at the supplied include and library files, not the binaries in the windows directory.

Comment: Also define "WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" in your project. That will avoid loading the very old Winsock 1 headers from Windows.h, which would create conflicts with Winsock 2 headers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the outdated SDK. I'm using vscode, not visual studio so I've checked my SDK version by looking at the file path of ws2_32.lib (which I found is 10.0.22621.0).
In the docs, it says that the minimum supported server (which I'm not sure what that is, but am assuming that's the SDK version) is Windows 10 build 20348. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-processsocketnotifications].
So it would seem that my SDK is up to date enough? If the minimum build is 20348 and mine is 22621

Comment: Actually, seems that my actual dll files might need to be updated, seeing that the .lib files are seemingly up to date. It seems (by the path name again) that the .dll files are of version 19041